# android database sqlite SQLiteConstraint exception constraint failed error

Tags: android, postgresql, sqlite

TABLE_NAME :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                    + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + NAME + " TEXT, "                  
                    + AGE + " TEXT, "

                    + LASTCHILDAGE + " TEXT, " 
                    + IMAGELOCATION + " TEXT);");
```

LMPDatabase entry=new LMPDatabase(Thankyou.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(name,age,imagelocation,ageofchild,trackingdate,status,lmpdate,mode,place);
                entry.close();

In Database:

```
public long createEntry(String name2, String age2, String imagelocation2, String lastchildage2,
        String trackingdate2, String status2, String lmpdate2, String mode2, String place2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Integer a=Integer.valueOf(age2);
    ContentValues cv1=new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(NAME, name2);
    cv1.put(AGE,a);
    cv1.put(LASTCHILDAGE, lastchildage2);
    cv1.put(IMAGELOCATION, imagelocation2);


    ContentValues cv2=new ContentValues();
    Integer i=getID();
    String d =Integer.toString(i);

    cv2.put(ID, d);
    cv2.put(TRACKINGDATE, trackingdate2);
    cv2.put(STATUS, status2);
    cv2.put(LMPDATE, lmpdate2);
    cv2.put(MODE, mode2);
    cv2.put(PLACE, place2);

    ourDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv1);
     return ourDB.insert(TABLE_LMP, null, cv2); 
}
```

[image: It shows this error]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert null value `(imagelocation=null)`. I think you forgot to check null constraint on imagelocation column.

Also make sure You're not inserting the same value for the column which is unique.